# Other selected rows on ListView selected but not highlighted

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, highlight

If I select ONE row in my ListView, it is highlighted but whenever I enter the MultipleSelection mode (onLongClick, # selected rows, Contextual Action Bar), other rows I select don't remain highlighted **BUT** is selected according to CAB as it says, "3 selected rows".

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout   
...
>
 <HorizontalScrollView
 ...
 >
    <LinearLayout
    ...
    >
        <TableLayout
        ...    
        >
            <TableRow
            ...
            >
                <TextView
                ... 
                />
                <TextView
                ... 
                />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/db_op_data_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/rowselector"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

rowselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selectable" /> 
<!-- focused -->

<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selectable" /> 
<!-- focused and pressed-->

<item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selected" /> 
<!-- pressed -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selectable" /> 
<!-- default -->
</selector>
```

EDIT: The image looks like this:
[Selected Rows but not Highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK0Tk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `state_selected` in your selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selectable" android:state_focused="true" />
    <!-- focused -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selectable" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- focused and pressed-->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- selected (ADD THIS) -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_button_selectable" />
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Not working. I've been racking my brains on this for days.

Comment: If it doesn't work with `state_selected` in xml then it means the view's selected stated is not set to true. You can try manually setting `setSelected(true)` inside Adapters `onItemClickListener`

Comment: I think the state_selected works but the application can't remember that I pressed it. I'm using  data_grid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()